# Yandex map provider for Silverlight DeepEarth

Tags: c#, silverlight, dictionary

Anybody know what need to do for adding yandex map to Silverlight deepearth?
Yandex map use different then google projection(epsg:3395) 
DeepEarth have class

```
public MercatorProjection()
        {
            GeoGCS = "GCS_WGS_1984";
            Datum = "WGS_1984";
            SpheroidRadius = 6378137.00D;
            SpheroidFlattening = 298.257223563D;
            Primem = 0.0D;
            AngularUnitOfMeasurement = 0.017453292519943295D;
            FalseEasting = 0.0;
            FalseNorthing = 0.0D;
            CentralMeridian = 0.0D;
            LatitudeOfOrigin = 0.0D;
            UnitAuthority = "Meter";

            ScaleX = HalfPi;
            ScaleY = -HalfPi;
            OffsetX = 0.5
            OffsetY = 0.5
        }
```

Which describe Merkator projection for Google, bing, openstreet maps. Maybe somebody know which params must be changed for epsg:3395 projection?

Comment: This is from Telerik. I'm also trying to figure it out...I also found this which might be a starting point.. http://jsfiddle.net/VkGjq/2/

Comment: you have succeeded?